# Upgrading Tomcat 7.0 - 8.5 or 9.0?

Tags: tomcat

I've recently inherited a system running Tomcat 7.0.68 and discovered that Tomcat 7 will reach end of life in March of 2021. I also learned that Tomcat 8.0 appears to have been superseded by both Tomcat 8.5 and 9.0, which seems confusing to me. Which is the recommended upgrade candidate? Are there pros and cons for one versus the other? I am currently running Java 1.8.0_74 but have later versions of Java 8 in use throughout our infrastructure. The web application we are running is THREDDS v4.6.10. Any recommendations or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is not with the tomcat itself, but with its compatibility with the apps running on it. You will also likely need to upgrade the JDK (JRE), meaning that you will have to modify the source of the likely very old projects running on it. Not too much, but you will have to. Now here is the problem coming: in the case of such old projects, typically there is zero funding to make the forward porting correctly. If you change anything, it will be *your fault*. This so likely since a decade. This is why you need to upgrade that fossil now.

Comment: Warn the "higher levels" (your bosses), but do nothing without their approval. The dangers are far bigger than they seem! Their likely answer will be some unclarity between a "do nothing" and "do the minimal change X". And you will need to live with that fossil, possibly far, far longer than you expect. It is unlikely that the project will be correctly updated to a recent tomcat, companies somehow never work so; it is far more likely that a completely new re-development with more recent technologies will happen.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The project hasn't touched this version of Tomcat (or Java, or THREDDS, for that matter) since setting up the server in June 2016, so the appetite (and certainly the budget) for change is minimal at best. We've been experiencing some OutOfMemory issues lately, but this seems more likely due to leaky code than any further middleware fossilization. I was hoping to use the OOM problems as leverage to upgrade Tomcat and Java, but I'm proceeding very cautiously. At this point I'm only in the information gathering phase.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a lot of difference between Tomcat 8.5 and 9.0: the former started as a fork of the first pre-release versions of Tomcat 9.0. Since the big changes in Java EE Servlet API came with version 3.0 (which is supported by Tomcat 7.0) I don't foresee any major problems with the migration to a newer Tomcat release.

I would choose Tomcat 9.0, since it is the *"last version you'll ever need"*, meaning that Tomcat 10.0 will use a binary incompatible standard Jakara EE Servlet 5.0 (basically they renamed the packages from `javax.servlet` to `jakarta.servlet`), so I think that Tomcat 9.0 will be around for a very long time.

Some things to take in mind during migration:

- setup a test server first, things like to break in unexpected ways,
- stick with Java SE 8.0, since it will be [supported at least until May 2026](https://adoptopenjdk.net/support.html) and because newer versions lack many Java EE APIs, which your applications may rely on (most notably JAXB),
- if you use a container managed connection pool, Tomcat 7.0 used `commons-dbcp`, while Tomcat 8.0+ uses `commons-dbcp2`, so you may want to tweak the connection pool parameters,

You don't mention the system you run Tomcat on. If you use Windows, I've seen many clients make the mistake to install a 32-bit Java (it's the first result you find on Google), which limits the available memory to around 2 GiB.

Answer (score 1):

Just to close the loop, we decided to use Tomcat 9.0.31 and Java 11.0.16, although admittedly the weakest link in the chain is the THREDDS app itself, now upgraded to version 5.4.